# JavaScript Iterate through cell child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I'm attempting to iterate through a html table in javascript and update the id's of the list items within a td tag. I'm currently having trouble on accessing these elements. The tags I need to access are;

```
<td>
  <li id='1'>Curly</li>
  <br />
  <li id='2'>Larry</li>
  <br />
  <li id='3'>Moe</li>
</td>
```

My current JavaScript is below which gets me to the cell. Can anyone advise how to access the Id's of the li?

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbl_calendar");

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Curious why you have a jQuery tag but you're not using it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all the `li`s within that cell in the example below using `querySelectorAll`. Also its not valid HTML to have `li`s without wrapping them in a `ul` or `ol`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ukgfekey/

JS:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbl_calendar");

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    var li = col.querySelectorAll('li');
    for (var index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
        alert(li[index].id + ': ' + li[index].textContent);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tbl_calendar">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li id='1'>Curly</li>
        <br />
        <li id='2'>Larry</li>
        <br />
        <li id='3'>Moe</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You also tagged jQuery so in best efforts to be fully explained.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ukgfekey/1/

var table = document.getElementById("tbl_calendar");

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    var li = $(col).find('li');
    for (var index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
            alert($(li[index]).attr('id') + ': ' + $(li[index]).text());
    }
  }
}
```

And as mentioned in comments you don't need all those loops. If you just want all `li`s from a table you could do this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ukgfekey/2/

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbl_calendar");

var li, lis = table.querySelectorAll('tr td li');
for (var index = 0; index < lis.length; index++) {
  li = lis[index];
  alert(li.id + ': ' + li.textContent);
}
```

Comment: I had the markup all mixed up in my head. Deleted my answer and +1 to you. If using `.querySelectorAll()`, you may want to show the OP how use `.table.querySelectorAll("tr > td > li")` with a single loop as well.

Comment: Thank you! Updated answer with your suggestion. =]

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using jQuery something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "td > li" ).each(function() {
          $( this ).attr("id","foo" );
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

AtheistP3ace already post a good answer but I'm new here and wanted to try to answer myself so here is a fiddle I made, not sure if it's what you want, I used jquery as I see it in your tags : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d63745r4/5/)

```
$("td").each(function() {
  $(this).find('li').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```